# Toast message is not coming in android studio phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, phonegap-plugins, android-toast

I am new to android studio.I am doing toast message for my app,but i am unable to do this one.This one is working in eclipse ,but no for android studio.I have tried a lot but the toast message is not showing at all.
Below is the code.Please suggest me.Thank you in advance.

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
         <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <title>Hello World</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="toastPlugin.js"></script>
        <script>
          function toast()
            {
               // alert('hii');
               // shortToast("Short Toast Message Here...");
               longToast("Long Toast Message Here...");
            }
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <div onclick="toast();">click</div>

            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

toastPlugin.js

```js
          window.shortToast = function(str, callback) {   
    cordova.exec(callback, function(err) {
        callback('Nothing to echo.');
    }, "ToastPlugin", "shortToast", [ str ]);
};

window.longToast = function(str, callback) {
   alert(str);//Long Toast Message Here...
    cordova.exec(callback, function(err) { alert("Nothing to echo");
        callback('Nothing to echo.');
    }, "ToastPlugin", "longToast", [ str ]);
};
```

ToastPlugin.java

```js
package com.raddyx.myapplication;

        import org.apache.cordova.api.CallbackContext;
        import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin;
        import org.json.JSONArray;
        import org.json.JSONException;

        import android.util.Log;
        import android.widget.Toast;

public class ToastPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {
    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args,
                           CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {

        String message = args.getString(0);

        // used to log the text and can be seen in LogCat
        Log.d("Toast Plugin", "Calling the Toast...");
        Log.d("Toast Plugin", message);

        if (action.equals("shortToast")) {
            this.shortToast(message, callbackContext);
            return true;
        } else if (action.equals("longToast")) {
            this.longToast(message, callbackContext);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void shortToast(String message, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
        if (message != null && message.length() > 0) {
            Toast.makeText(cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                    message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            callbackContext.success(message);
        } else {
            callbackContext.error("Expected one non-empty string argument.");
        }
    }

    private void longToast(String message, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
        if (message != null && message.length() > 0) {
            Toast.makeText(cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                    message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            callbackContext.success(message);
        } else {
            callbackContext.error("Expected one non-empty string argument.");
        }
    }
}
```

In config.xml

```html
 <feature name="ToastPlugin"> <param name="android-package" value="com.raddyx.plugins.ToastPlugin" /> </feature>
```

Comment: `cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext()` where is this `Object` initialized? cordova? and what is your logcat?

Comment: Will i put  cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext();    in  ToastPlugin.java ?  @ helldawg

Comment: the cordova Object is not initialized so that probably is giving you NullPointerException

Comment: Is there any reason not to use a existing toast plugin like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-x-toast)?

Comment: Ok i am cheking.@helldawg13

Answer (score 1):

#### PhoneGap Toast plugin

Install toast popup plugin for iOS, Android and WP8 Cordova apps using **[CLI](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/index.html)**

*[cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-x-toast](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Toast-PhoneGap-Plugin)*

Then add`cordova_plugins.js` in your `index.html` and call following function

**showShortTop(message)**

```
window.plugins.toast.showShortTop('Hello there!', function(a) {
    console.log('toast success: ' + a);
}, function(b) {
    alert('toast error: ' + b);
})
```

**showLongBottom(message)**

```
window.plugins.toast.showLongBottom('Hello there!', function(a) {
     console.log('toast success: ' + a)
}, function(b) {
     alert('toast error: ' + b)
})
```

Comment: Hello,I am facing problem in create app stage.

Comment: Here as per the document,app will be create in the directory of sourse code.which is d:/xampp/htdocs ,but it is creating in d .how can i change it in cmd?

Comment: Hii i got it.Doing the next step.Thank you.

Comment: Hii,i am facing one more problem.

Comment: Its showing toast error :Class not found and  in studio i saw something error like 
I/System.out: Error adding plugin nl.xservices.plugins.Toast.

Comment: are you installed plugin successfully or not..?

Comment: I have installed it,but i am not sure is it working or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101243/discussion-between-srd-and-ved).